# Differences between these two methods to include Matlab figures in a Powerpoint presentation

Tags: matlab, graphics, drawing, powerpoint, figure

I want to include Matlab figures in a Powerpoint presentation. [Note that in other contexts, I usually use LaTeX beamer with `.eps` files, but here I am obliged to use Powerpoint.]

I know two ways:

1. Save the image as e.g. a `.tiff` file and include the image in Powerpoint. The result does not always look sharp and some lines are too thin.
2. Copy the image directly in Matlab and paste it in Powerpoint. The resulting figure is way nicer. But after exporting the Powerpoint to pdf, it may take some time to load the figure (especially when you included `grid minor`).

What is the difference between these two methods: is it the well-known bitmap vs. vector image difference or something else? Is there a way to have the quality of the second method but without the problem that is loads slowly?

Comment: _is it the well-known bitmap vs. vector image_ I bet on that. Also, check (in Matlab's options) the format used when copying figure to clipboard

Comment: And can this explain the fact that figures with a lot of lines are loaded with some delay in an exported pdf?